# MPAndroidChart Scatter points are cropped in Combined chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use combined chart which combines line (RED) and scatter charts. However for some reason scatter chart points are cropped at the edge of chart here is example:

[image]

**Is there any way to prevent it?**

here is my chart code:

```
    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(1.1f);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    chart.setDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.setNoDataText("");
```

and my scatter data set:

```
    foodDataSet = new ScatterDataSet(foodEntries, "Food");
    foodDataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green_main));
    foodDataSet.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    foodDataSet.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    foodDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    foodDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

**Update** 
[image]

here is chart with axis 
[image]

Comment: Can you please add image with marking of cropped at the edge?

Comment: Added more samples

Comment: On scroll, either right or left, can you able to see full points?

Comment: Scroll is disabled,  I don't need scroll

Comment: As of now, for testing, please add `chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(7);` and check.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Try this `chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(7);`.

Comment: No that brakes chart, all points are shown on 0 x value

Comment: Check this method: `XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);`

Comment: /**
     * if set to true, the chart will avoid that the first and last label entry
     * in the chart "clip" off the edge of the chart or the screen
     * 
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setAvoidFirstLastClipping(boolean enabled) {
        mAvoidFirstLastClipping = enabled;
    }

it just affects label

Comment: chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(xAxisLabels.size() - 0.92f);  solves half of issue, all points at the end of chart a displayed fully, however values at X-0 still are cropped

Comment: Great! Try to increase 0.92f to 1 or 1.15.

Comment: Increasing the value can't help, it only affect right side of chart, as chart still starts from 0 and at that position points are still cropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries I was able to find hack to solve issue. However it would be good if proper solution could be advised. Current solution

```
chart.setData(data);
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(-0.1f);
chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(xAxisLabels.size() - 0.81f);
chart.invalidate();
```

Min value should be increased if bigger data points are used, but it will require update min visible x range too. Reduce subtraction value to increase offset.

Disadvantage of such solution is it doesn't scale well

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this problem, here's what I did to make mine scale with the number of entries. This assumes that the number of entries is the same for each data set which may or may not be the case for your specific data.

```
    float xAxisSideOffset = (float)(xMax - xMin) / (data.getEntryCount()/data.getDataSetCount());

    combinedChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(xMin - timeInterval - xAxisSideOffset/2);
    combinedChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(xMax - timeInterval + xAxisSideOffset/2);
```